# Device connected to the router, but I can't open any new webpages

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I am using Shaw Cable service with a modem-router combo. We have anywhere from 0 to 7 devices connected at a time. All of them can connect to the internet, but after a while, the internet fails to work. Windows shows that the connection is fine or shows the yellow triangle, but I can still access the router settings. Any previous ongoing downloads are uninterrupted. However, I cannot start any new downloads or open any new webpages. Resetting the adapter usually reconnects the device, but the problem happens all over again.

I chatted with a Shaw tech support representative. After a few questions, he told me that the modem was showing offline on his side. At this point, I noticed that I could not open any new webpages, but I could still chat with him. He tried adding another ip to the modem and resetting it, but it didn't help.

Comment: Are you using a modem-router combo device? Does the issue occur only when connected via wifi?

Comment: Yes I am using a modem-router. I have not tried using ethernet yet but I will see if the problem happens with it.

Comment: Are you using any clustering download services? What are these "ongoing downloads" you're talking about?

Comment: I just happened to be downloading a big file at the time (~1.5 GB).

Comment: @RednBlack Using what service? If you're using something that uses multiple connections (like torrent downloaders) you may have hit your router's connection limit.

Comment: It was a download from http, not a torrent. Also, how do you find out your router's connection limit?

Comment: @P Fitz The same problem happens on ethernet.